# Could not load Images in GridView builder()

Tags: flutter, dart

i am beginner in Flutter , i am trying to create a gridview builder with a card that contains an image, the gridview. builder in the bottom works fine but the gridview builder on the top do not load any image, the difference of the both gridviews is that the one that have problem : the image is inside a card,
I do not have any idea why the second works and the one on the top do not do that even they use the same assets
the error i am getting is about Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI for every asset

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/clubs/Clubs.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/results/results.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/schedules/schedules.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/stats/player_goals.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/tables%20copy/league_board.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/stats/player_assists.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/stats/player_red_cards.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/stats/player_yellow_cards.dart';


class Statss extends StatelessWidget {


  List<String> images = [
    "Assets/tt.jpg",
    "Assets/qatarairways.jpg",
    "Assets/LOGO_Danao.jpg",
    "Assets/delice.jpg"
  ];

  List<String> menu = [
    "Assets/tt.jpg",
    "Assets/qatarairways.jpg",
    "Assets/LOGO_Danao.jpg",
    "Assets/delice.jpg"
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Stats"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue[300],
          elevation: 0.0,
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                  colors: [Colors.purple, Colors.blue])),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                child: Text(
                  "Statistiques",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                      color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: GridView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: menu.length,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 1.0),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Card(
                      elevation: 4.0,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child:
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              height: 60,
                              width: 60,
                              child:
                              Image.network(menu[index]),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(width:10.0),

                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),

              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 30, 15, 0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 1,
                    ),
                    ButtonTheme(
                      minWidth: double.infinity,
                      height: 40,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                          child: Align(
                            child: Text(
                              "Top Scorers",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                            ),
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Scorers()),
                            );
                          },
                          color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                          textColor: Colors.black,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                          splashColor: Colors.green,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 1,
                    ),
                    ButtonTheme(
                      minWidth: double.infinity,
                      height: 40,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                          child: Align(
                            child: Text(
                              "Top Assists",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                            ),
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Assists()),
                            );
                          },
                          color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                          textColor: Colors.black,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                          splashColor: Colors.green,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 1,
                    ),
                    ButtonTheme(
                      minWidth: double.infinity,
                      height: 40,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                          child: Align(
                            child: Text(
                              "Yellow Cards",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                            ),
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YellowCards()),
                            );
                          },
                          color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                          textColor: Colors.black,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                          splashColor: Colors.green,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(
                      height: 1,
                    ),
                    ButtonTheme(
                      minWidth: double.infinity,
                      height: 40,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                          child: Align(
                            child: Text(
                              "Red Cards",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                            ),
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RedCards()),
                            );
                          },
                          color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                          textColor: Colors.black,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                          splashColor: Colors.green,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: images.length,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 4.0),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Image.asset(images[index]);
                    },
                  ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

here how it looks:
[image]

i am tryin to make it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using `Image.network(menu[index])` for the top gridview.

change it to

`Image.asset(menu[index])`, it'll work, because you are loading your images from your assets, and not anything from the network.

Comment: i did this it works thank you , but when i try to make images with larger screen it does not work, how to make these images with full width?

Comment: `Image.asset(menu[index], fit: BoxFit.fitWidth)`. Please consider marking this as an answer to your question, thanks!

Comment: and how to make the image rounded?

Comment: Use rounded border radius on your container which surrounds your Image.asset.